# Return the position of cell using index

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Here is the table image]
[image]

As you can see The expected output I want and what I have actually got

when I use index I get value and When I use match I don't satisfy the condition.

I want to return the position of Rachana Aggarwal in the table using index and match such as position 7 in this case
I have shown the formula I have used in the Excel screenshot for Position column in the query

Comment: I very much hope this is anonymized data.

Comment: This is sample data from my course

Comment: What is the expected result and where? Share a few examples.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I have inserted a screenshot for better understanding

Comment: I don't quite understand task #3. To find the position of one item in a list, the function is MATCH ... I don't see where INDEX comes in, the formula would be `=MATCH(B21,B1:B11,0)-1`. If you then want the value of that match, you can use INDEX.

Comment: yes me neither I wanted to use match but idk what is it about index

Comment: Match() gives the position in a list, then that result can be used in index() to drive row and column.

Comment: Then your question is better directed at the person who set the task. As an aside, this is a classic use for Excel `Table`s: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c

Comment: @Akshay, people who set homework, just like people who do homework, don't always get it right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use index + match. Use only MATCH and substract rows of headers: `=MATCH(B21, B1:B11,0) - 1`